# extracting .backup files created by android recovery

Tags: android, compression, backup, file-type, data-extraction

I have .backup files created in recovery mode of my android device. I want to mount this backup file in my linux system.

I'v tried to extract them as tar file or tar.gz but that didn't work. What is the format of these files? Is it possible to extract and mount them at all?

Comment: what does `file` command say?

Comment: @pskink  "data" !

Comment: that's bad ;-( what about `hexdump -C <fileName> | head -3` ?

Comment: yup, black magic ;-( sorry...

Comment: @pskink yes, thanks anyway ...

Comment: Does the file start with "ANDROID BACKUP"?

Comment: @MarkAdler here is the output of  hexdump -C <fileName> | head -3 :
 
00000000  05 52 82 60 84 db b2 33  61 9c ec 9b 78 80 06 10  |.R.`...3a...x...|

00000010  53 fc 94 4c 8a 93 2e a9  27 c5 3a 70 88 99 97 63  |S..L....'.:p...c|

00000020  07 65 ce f1 c3 d3 ec 60  06 08 6d d7 fa 00 16 2a  |.e.....`..m....*|

Comment: No clue. Not finding any deflate data in there.